# WkWebView not allow to zoom some website after loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, zooming

Here i added programmatically my WkWebView in to main view, then after i added this delegate for WkWebView

```
self.wkWebView.UIDelegate = self;
self.wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
wkWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

and then loading website one by one and checking zoom functionality, it's zooming for some website and not zooming for other website

If i am loading **http://www.google.com** - then it's allow to me for zooming
and if i am loading **https://www.42gears.com** & **https://www.facebook.com** - then it's not allow to zooming functionality (This all website's zooming is working in safari, but not working in WKWebView)

Note : i am checking in iPhone and i am working with Objective-C

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i evaluate Javascript for zooming functionality, and here you need to add this in **didFinishNavigation** method. so using this you can fix this issue.

```
bool isAllowZoom = false;

-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
{
   if(isAllowZoom){
        NSString *javascript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=yes');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
       [webView evaluateJavaScript:javascript completionHandler:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *javascript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
        [webView evaluateJavaScript:javascript completionHandler:nil];
    }
}
```

Thanks, may be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> updated Sapana Ranipa answer on swift 4 on Xcode 11 , iOS 12 ,13

```
let isAllowZoom: Bool = false

  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didFinish navigation")
        self.activityIndicatorwbweb.stopAnimating()

        if(isAllowZoom){
          let javascript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=yes');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
            webViewWB.evaluateJavaScript(javascript, completionHandler: nil)
        }
        else
        {

             let javascript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
             webViewWB.evaluateJavaScript(javascript, completionHandler: nil)
        }

    }
```